# Transform csv file from vertical data to horizontal with python

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a python script.
Most of my data are recorded in a vertical model and I want to have them in a horizontal.

here is my example of the data I've

```
ID,Identifier,Value
1_UK,City,Paris
1_UK,Number of the departments,75
1_UK,Department,Ile de France
1_UK,Habitant,12405426hab
2_UK,City,Ajaccio
2_UK,Number of the departments,2A
2_UK,Department,Corse du Sud
```

And here is where I want to go:

```
ID, City, Number of the departments, Department, Habitant
1_UK, Paris, 75, Ile de France, 12405426hab
2_UK, Ajaccio, 2A, Corse du sud,''
```

To read a CSV file in Python is not difficult. Where I'm lost is I've 4 identifier (city, number of the departments, department and habitant)
the ID 2_UK doesn't have a value for habitant. And I don't know how to represent that in my code.

```
import csv
csvfile = open ("Exercice1.csv",'r',encoding='utf-8')
IDs=[]
identifiers=[]
uniqueIDs=[]
uniqueidentifiers=[]
reader=csv.reader(csvfile)

for row in reader:    
    IDs.append(ID)
    identifiers.append(identifier)
csvfile.close()

#remove duplicate value and keep order as is it.
for i in IDs:
    if i not in uniqueIDs:
        uniqueIDs.append(i)

for i in identifiers:
    if i not in uniqueidentifiers:
        uniqueidentifiers.append(i)
```

And then I'm lost
the function zip seems to not answer to my needs or I don't use it properly.

Happy to listen your advice.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to include a complete working example - your sample code cannot run

Comment: Is the header _fixed_, as in will the output CSV only have the defined columns? Also, are the values in the first column ordered / not mixed (i.e. `1_UK` will never appear after `2_UK`)?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy using `pandas`. You can import your `.csv` file into a DataFrame `df` and then using `pivot`:

```
In [10]: d = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Identifier', values='Value')

In [11]: d
Out[11]: 
Identifier     City     Department     Habitant Number of the departments
ID                                                                       
1_UK          Paris  Ile de France  12405426hab                        75
2_UK        Ajaccio   Corse du Sud         None                        2A
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment both of you. The use of panda makes the work super efficient! I like it. My real file is more complicated I've in a way two values depending of the type of data that will be on the column value or value2. I'll investigate to see if I can put that together.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
import csv

cities = {}
with open('Exercice1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for d in reader:
        new_dict = {d['Identifier']: d['Value'], 'ID': d['ID']}
        try:
            cities[d['ID']] = {**cities[d['ID']], **new_dict}
        except KeyError:
            cities[d['ID']] = {**new_dict}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    field_names = ['ID', 'City', 'Number of the departments', 'Department', 'Habitant']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=field_names, lineterminator='\n', restval='')

    writer.writeheader()
    for k, v in cities.items():
        writer.writerow(v)
```

Using your data this gives me:

```
ID,City,Number of the departments,Department,Habitant
1_UK,Paris,75,Ile de France,12405426hab
2_UK,Ajaccio,2A,Corse du Sud,
```

The `restval` argument in `csv.DictWriter` is what is inserted in a row if the dict provided doesn't have a key from the `field_names` list. I just used an empty string, you could replace it with whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I need to spend more time to replicate your solution on my script. I'll let you know the result :)