# How to convert vertical csv file to horizontally

Tags: python, csv

I want to convert the inputted csv.data result horizontal to vertical.

This is my code

```
import csv
with open('p1.csv', newline='') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f)
 for row in reader:
  rain=(", ".join(row))
  print(rain)
```

This is the result

```
4.019310345
6.713103448
1.172413793
2.369655172
0.485517241
```

I want it to be like below.

```
4.019310345, 6.713103448, 1.172413793, 2.369655172, 0.485517241
```

I have tried 'replace' function, it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform csv file from vertical data to horizontal with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478723/transform-csv-file-from-vertical-data-to-horizontal-with-python)

Comment: You're looping over every row and joining what's on each row, but since there's only one value on each row, you still get one value on each line - have you tried getting rid of the `for` and just `rain=(", ".join(reader))`?

Comment: Yes if I rid of the for command, it gives me IndentationError

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
import csv
csv_file = r"My_file_path"
with open(csv_file, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rain = []
    for row in reader:
        rain.append(row)   
    print(', '.join(rain))
```

Here I'm creating a separate list named as rain and after the loop I'm printing the list with the help of join.

Comment: Thank you I made it! It was very helpful